# increment_version_number not working in workspace

Tags: xcode, react-native, fastlane

I'm trying to increase the build and version numbers of my React Native (0.60) apps with fastlane.

`increase_build_number` works fine, however  `increase_version_number` produces this error :
`Can't increment version`

I've followed the recommended guide from the error with no luck - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1827/_index.html

Does `increase_version_number` work with a `.xcworkspace`?

Comment: It does not accept a workspace as a parameter. [Here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/increment_version_number.rb) is the source code. It seems to depend on the current working directory to run the command.

Comment: What do you see when you run `agvtool what-marketing-version -terse1` from the directory of your project (the parent directory of your `fastlane` directory). Whatever that command is outputting, cannot be parsed into a version string (major.minor.patch, ie 11.0.0).

Comment: @andyaladdin did you ever get this working?

Comment: @bataleon I pointed it towards the xcode project instead.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by first following instructions by Apple here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html

Then in the final step, I changed `Bundle version string (short)` `(CFBundleShortVersionString)` from $(MARKETING_VERSION) to 0.1.0

Hope this helps.